# Should I create new constructor only for test purposes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, integration-testing

I have a class that contains two dimensional array of another object. It has one constructor, but inside that array is initialized always with zeros. So, `Others` is not initialized to be fair:

```
public class FirstClass
{
    public OtherClass[,] Others { get; set; }

    ...

}

public class OtherClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This array `Others` is populated during the runtime. Now, I'd like to write a test, that will test some operations when `Others` is populated. So I need to pass sample arrays to Test methods. I didn't want to create arrays of `OtherClass` because I have many of those sample arrays and I will have to write:

```
        OtherClass[][,] samples = new[]
        {
            new OtherClass[,]
            {
                { new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };},
                { new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };,new OtherClass() { Id = 2 };},

etc..
```

**UGLY!**

So in my `Tests` project I created arrays just of ints (`Id`s):

```
    int[][,] samples = new[]
    {
        new int[,]
        {
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,2,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,3,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,4,0,0,0}
        },
        new int[,]
        {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
        }
    };
```

much more readable... but now I need to create a constructor for `FirstClass`, that takes `int[,]` as parameter and create OtherClass[,] with Ids from parameter.

Theoretically I should be good, because test would looks like:

```
[TestFixture]
class BoardTests
{
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("samples")]
    public void FirstTest(int[,] board)
    {
        FirstClass aClass = new FirstClass(board);
        //Test an operation on aClass 
    }
}
```

**So, my question is:**
Is it good practice to create additional constructor **ONLY** for tests? I will not use this constructor in production code. Or do you have better solution?

Comment: Just a question, anyways the 'Others' is exposed as a public property, so Why not just initialize it with whatever values you want in your test?

Comment: You can create a separate class that makes the mapping between int[,] and Other[] (the same code that you are going to write in the new constructor). In this way you separate the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I need to create a constructor for `FirstClass`, that takes `int[,]` as parameter and create `OtherClass[,]` with `Id`s from parameter.

Although this is certainly an option, you certainly don't *have to* do it if you prefer. A solution that keeps your constructors unchanged is to make a private method in your test class to convert `int[,]` to `OtherClass[,]`:

```
private static ToOtherClass(int[,] ids) {
    var OtherClass[,] res = ...
    // Do the conversion here
    return res;
}
```

Now you can use this method to produce easy-to-read code that does not use a special constructor:

```
OtherClass[][,] samples = new[]
{
    ToOtherClass( new int[,]
    {
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,2,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,3,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,4,0,0,0}
    }),
    ToOtherClass( new int[,]
    {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    })
};
```

Comment: I thougt about such coverter. I just wasn't sure if implementig additional logic just for test is good practice

Comment: @AnnaLong There is no question about having to implement this logic for testing, the only question is where this logic going to be. Constructors is not a good place for test-only logic, because they remain in the finished code. Test fixtures, on the other hand, are a perfect place for such logic, because they are not given to users of your library.

Comment: You're right, that makes sense. One last question: Why your `ToOtherClass` method is static? I've never thought about that, but `TestFixture` class doesn't need to be instantiated anyway..

Comment: @AnnaLong `ToOtherClass` is what's commonly called a "helper method". It belongs to your test fixture, and helps you define your tests in a more readable format. Helper methods like this should be kept static, unless, of course, they use instance variables of your test fixture.